# JBoss web service client host url configuration

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I have a ejb3 using a web service and configure the host name of the web service in the ejb-jar.xml file (or  @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http:://myserver/service.wsdl") ). Can I do the same configure outside of the ejb-jar.xml file, similar to how a DataSource is configured?

Comment: You may want to clarify what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use deployment descriptors to override settings made by annotations. 
Maybe you can inject the values from outside, declaring a class similar to that what is described here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_devwbsjaxwsclient_dyn.html